# Getting table data into Gridview in C# (SQLite) is not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqlite, gridview

I want to show my data that I have stored in a SQLite database in an ASP.net page which I code in C#. 
I searched a lot on the internet and in my previous question someone showed me a really helpfull article. I used the code but it still doesn't work.

What I want is to get the first three columns in my gridview. So "woord", "vertaling" and "gebruiker" from the table "tbWoorden" should be displayed in the gridview.
[image]

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Scripts_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString =
         @"Data Source=C:/Users/elias/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/WebSites/WebSite7/App_Data/overhoren.db";

        using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataSet dsTest = new DataSet();


            // Create a SELECT query. 
            string strSelectCmd = "SELECT woord,vertaling,gebruiker FROM tbWoorden";


            // Create a SqlDataAdapter object 
            // SqlDataAdapter represents a set of data commands and a  
            // database connection that are used to fill the DataSet and  
            // update a SQL Server database.  
            SqlDataAdapter da = NewMethod(conn, strSelectCmd);


            // Fill the DataTable named "Person" in DataSet with the rows 
            // returned by the query.new n 
            da.Fill(dsTest, "tbWoorden");


            // Get the DataView from Person DataTable. 
            DataView dvPerson = dsTest.Tables["tbWoorden"].DefaultView;


            // Set the sort column and sort order. 
            dvPerson.Sort = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();


            // Bind the GridView control. 
            grdMijnLijsten.DataSource = dvPerson;
            grdMijnLijsten.DataBind();

            using (var command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                command.Connection = conn;

                command.CommandText =
                   @"SELECT[vertaling], [woord] FROM[tbWoorden] WHERE[woord] = 'ans'";



                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string test = "";



                }
            }



        }
    }

    private static SqlDataAdapter NewMethod(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn, string strSelectCmd)
    {
        return new SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, conn);
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void grdMijnLijsten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The error I get is: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection' to 'string'.
*The part that causes the error is the conn string in the NewMethod:*

```
private static SqlDataAdapter NewMethod(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn, string strSelectCmd)
{
    return new SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, conn);
}
```

What do I have to change? 
Thanks in advance, Elias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `SQLiteDataAdapter` (from the SQLite family) instead of `SqlDataAdapter` (which is part of the SQLClient family)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed fixed it. For others reading this: make sure you are using system.data.SQLite (I forgot)